# Office 365 Equivalent of GSuite Email Logs Export to Big Query?

Tags: office365

Does Office 365 have the equivalent of GSuite Enterprise's ability to export email logs to a service such as Big Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big Query is Relational DBMS of Google while Microsoft has different Relational DBMS like SQL Server & Microsoft Access. But as far as I understood from your question, your actual requirement is to export emails log or some thing like email tracking.

For this I'll recommended you to use Message Tracking (Microsoft Exchange - Office 365). The message tracking log is a detailed record of all activity as mail flows through the transport pipeline on Mailbox servers and Edge Transport servers. You can use message tracking for message forensics, mail flow analysis, reporting, and troubleshooting.

For more details about Message Tracking in Office365, you can [click here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124375(v=exchg.160).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Hemant! That is helpful. The message tracking log is what I'm after. But what I'm really interested to know is if Office365 has a built-in pipe to say Hadoop on Azure or if there is an easy setup for piping the data out. Those logs cycle and need to be stored...the only option I could find was using Powershell script.

Comment: Yes Andrew.. As far as I know, Powershell is the only option. You can schedule those powershell scripts as a batch file or web job which will get executed at specific interval and you will have specific log cycle which can be stored anywhere.

Comment: I'll also try to find out any another way and will update the answer as soon as I'll find any another option which can meet your requirement.